# why my code (http connection android) doesn't work

Tags: java, android

im trying to make an app to connect Internet and Return Html . 
but it doesnt work & i dont know the reason ! 
please help me to fix my problems : tnQ

**Error :** 
**java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message**

my code :

```
package net.learn2develop.http3; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        Log.d("location", " 0 as start");

        InputStream in=null;
        int response=-1;
        String urlString="http://www.tabnak.ir";
        try
        {
        URL url=new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
        if(!(conn instanceof  HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not ann HTTP Connection");
        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn=(HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response=httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if(response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {in=httpConn.getInputStream();}
            else{ 
                Log.d("location", " 1");
                }
            TextView intxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytxt); 
            intxt.setText(in.toString());

        }
        catch(Exception ex0)
        {
            Log.d("e:",ex0.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("location 2 Exception : ", ex.toString());
        }




        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    }
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear I think?

Comment: Realy ? so solve it please! im new in android

Comment: You should do  TextView intxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytxt); 
            intxt.setText(in.toString()); only if the response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK is true.

Comment: Where's your println?

Comment: it doesnt work ! i dont have any println !

Comment: it does work, because is not crashing. on the else part, print your reponse. You are not getting the 200 reponse (OK).

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend the using of this library http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

With this , you simple have to put this piece of code and fit it with your needs in the onSuccess method.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.tabnak.ir", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

@Override
public void onStart() {
    // called before request is started
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
    // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
    // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
}

@Override
public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
    // called when request is retried
}
```

});